# Decrypt 3des cfb string in bash

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl, 3des

i want to decrypt a string using openssl but it keeps saying :
non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value

I am using this command:

```
openssl enc -d -in crypt -out file.txt -K mypas -iv iv.txt -p -des-ede3-cfb
```

mypas = 1D5sqZr QEG5ZEY54shhGE9

iv.txt = 2cd3e7471d9da0ef

crypt = 25cc14697f9f2106adcf2e48

what am I doing wrong?

the string is encrypted 3DES in CFB mode.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

from `openssl enc --help`:

```
-K/-iv         key/iv in hex is the next argument
```

You have to specify the iv and key in hex. Not as filenames.

I can't make sense of your data, but here's an example:

```
$ od -t x1 file.bin
0000000 43 f7 fd 5b 39 fd 5c 70 66 d2 8f 67 2a 5d fd
0000017

$ openssl enc -d -in file.bin -out file.txt \
    -K 4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F \
    -iv 524f464c524f464c -p -des-ede3-cfb
salt=B8FCBCBF6448EAB7
key=4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F4C4F
iv =524F464C524F464C

$ cat file.txt
this is a test
```